How to solve partial derivative problem? Help
Title: Finding Mixed Partial Derivatives and Extrema for a Transformed Function ( z = f(u, v) )

Question:
I am working on a problem involving a function ( z = f(u, v) ) with second-order continuous partial derivatives. The variables ( u ) and ( v ) are transformations of ( x ) and ( y ), defined as:
$$
u = x - \frac{1}{2}y, \quad v = x + \frac{1}{2}y.
$$
Additionally, the following condition is given:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} - 4 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 12a, \quad a \neq 0.
$$
The problem has two parts:

Find the mixed partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}$.

Given the following conditions:
$$
   \frac{\partial f(u, 0)}{\partial u} = -3u^2, \quad f(0, v) = -v^3,
   $$
determine the extremum of ( f(u, v) ).



What I Know and Tried:

I understand that ( u ) and ( v ) are linear combinations of ( x ) and ( y ), and I suspect I need to use the chain rule to express $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}$in terms of $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}$.

I tried to compute the partial derivatives for part (1), but I am unsure how to handle the transformation between $(x, y)$ and $(u, v)$ correctly.

For part (2), I know that finding extrema involves checking where the gradient $\nabla f(u, v)$ is zero, but the given partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} $and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ make me unsure of the next steps.



What I Don’t Understand:

How to effectively use the given condition
$$
  \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} - 4 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 12a
  $$
to find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}$.

How to incorporate the given partial derivatives to find the extremum of $f(u, v)$. Is there a trick I’m missing?


Any help with these steps would be greatly appreciated!

Edit your post to include the specifics of (1) and (2). Also, you should write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,0)$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Part 1:
You need to find the relationships between variables:
$$u = x - \frac{1}{2}y, \quad v = x + \frac{1}{2}y$$
Find:
$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}$
Express ($x, y$) in terms of ($u, v$):
$$x = \frac{u+v}{2}, \quad y = v-u$$
Use chain rule to express partial derivates:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
Then calculate second order derivatives similarly.
Using the given condition, use it to solfe for mixed partial derivates ($\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}$):
$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} - 4 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 12a$$
Part 2:
Determine the Exxtremum of $f(u, v)$ using given conditions:
$$\frac{\partial f(u, 0)}{\partial u} = -3u^2, \quad f(0, v) = -v^3$$
Then you need to find the critical points by setting the gradient to zero:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = 0$$
Evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ using the transformation and given condition. Then determine second order conditions and identify their extremum points using the Hessian Matrix.
From the condition $f(0, v) = -v^3$, differentiate with respect to $v$:
$$\frac{\partial f(0, v)}{\partial v} = -3v^2$$
Your gradient components should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = -3u^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = -3v^2$. Set both equal to zero for critical points:
$$-3u^2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad u = 0$$
$$-3v^2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad v = 0$$
Now using the Hessian matrix, mentioned before of $f(u, v)$ is:
$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} \\\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now calculating the second order derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(-3u^2) = -6u$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(-3v^2) = -6v$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} = 0$$
At the critical point $(u, v) = (0, 0)$:
$$H(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The second derivative test is inconclusive since the Hessian at the critical point $(u, v)$ is a zero matrix. I think my answer may be wrong, but the solution approach is correct.
